# a accident error for loc function in Xarry

Tags: python-xarray

I try to use the loc function to select the specific dimension. But now, I got the error :'
TypeError: get_loc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'.

It is very strange, because I used this command to choose the data yesterday.

The Xarray version is 0.16.0, the Pandas version is 2.0.2.

The detaile for the data is:
[image]
The command is below:`amazon_data.loc[2000,15,:,:]`

Comment: Please update your question with a minimal / reproducible example. There is not nearly enough to go off here.